# apache - mod_rewrite - redirect some paths to https others to http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

My company wants our site to force an http protocol for most of the site except for three sections 'user', 'shop', and 'cart'. I used the online .htaccess tester at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to build my file first, and it appeared to be correct there. However, when I actually implemented it I had a problem. If I go to https for any of the regular pages it works and I'm redirected to the http version just fine. However if I go to '/shop', '/cart', or '/user' no matter if it's with http or https i just get redirected to the home page with http. Here's the .htaccess file:

```
  RewriteEngion on
  # Force HTTPS for /shop
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /shop
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

  # Force HTTPS for /cart
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /cart
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

  # Force HTTPS for /user
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /user
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

  # Force HTTP for all others
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/cart [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/shop [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/user [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `THE_REQUEST` variable in your conditions.  `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

```
  # Force HTTPS for cart, shop, user
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(cart|shop|user) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

  # Force HTTP for all others
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/(cart|shop|user) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```